# How to add CloudFront as a trigger for lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I tried to create a lambda@edge for cloudfront redirect root default object. I followed this instruction: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

But the CloudFront doesn't appear in the trigger selection. How can I add CloudFront as a trigger for my lambda function?

[image]

Comment: In which region is your lambda deployed?

Answer (score 4):

For those who are struggling this error, I solve it by changing the region to US East V N

Comment: ajudou bastante =)

Answer (score 2):

The Cloudfront triggers are supported in N. Virginia region. So, for using ClodFront Triggers you have to Create you lambda in Virginia Region. And then you will be able to see CloudFront Trigger inside the Designer tab. [image: Designer tab]